# Find images that take up all the width but just 25% of the page height

Tags: css, image

I am not able to find images that would take up the full width of the page and just 25% per cent of the page height. As soon as I change the css of the image, it looks weird since its width is too big compared to the height. Does anybody have an idea about where I could find images that work with this? or how I should deal with this?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Is you problem about your images width & height ratio ?

Comment: @AlexisWollseifen yes exactly that.

Answer (score 1):

You have many ways to fix this. An easy one is to use `background-image` property instead of `<img>` tags.

eg:

```
div.image {
  background-image: url('your/img/path.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover (will cover all the div surface) || contain (will fully contains your image);
}
```

Fiddle :

```css
div.image {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vh;
  
  background-image: url('http://musiccitiessummit.com/wp-content/uploads/chicago-1.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  
  background-position: center center;
}
```

```html
<div class="image"></div>
```

**EDIT**
If you have to work with `<img>` tags, take a look at this `object-fit` property : https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/object-fit/

Answer (score 0):

There is no one image to fit all scenarios since there are many screens with different aspect ratio and different resolutions.

You must clarify you Art Direction and your responsiveness on how your page will look according to the view port size.
You must use @media and also have a look at the picture element, the source element and the srcset attribute since your page must be mobile friendly first